# DTLS implementation for SCTP connections

Tags: openssl, sctp, dtls

I am trying to do DTLS implementation for SCTP connections. I searched through web and found many of the implementations refers to link. But this link is not working.

http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html.

Can someone shared a sample code for DTLS over SCTP using openSSL ? The documentation of openssl is very verbose does not document all the API's well.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

I found the web archives of DTLS SCTP sample code

http://web.archive.org/web/20150617012520/http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html